# Button text change before appearing in the new html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem: I am changing the text of a button depending on a click from the previous page, so I tried using JavaScript to update the `innerHTML` of the button in the new page using the `onload()` event for the body of the new page. But, it appears for the user when it changes its text. I just want it to appear directly without the change being noticeable to the user. Has anyone got the answer for this?

```js
function myFunction(){
  var x=document.getElementById("GymName");
  x.innerHTML="hesham";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()" >
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="GymName">Omar</button>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? When I run this code, it changes the `innerHTML` of the button to the "hesham" value when the page loads. Is that not what you want?

Comment: nope, i want the text of the button to change before i view this page as it appears to me when i open the page as if it's a transition. i want it to be completely transparent to the user. not seeing this change

Comment: OK, so you are seeing the value "Omar" in the button, and then the new value, and you just never want to see the "Omar" value?

Comment: yep exactly, and for further information, this page is loaded upon a click on a certain image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the button hidden with `display: none`, and only show it after the value is changed. Or, if you're looking for a smoother transition you could [fade it in with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/).

```js
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("GymName");
  x.innerHTML = "hesham";
  x.style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
#GymName {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" >
  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="GymName">Omar</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the function invoke immediately as it's defined:

```
(function () {
  document.getElementById("GymName").innerHTML = 'hesham';
}());
```

As in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="GymName">Omar</button>
<script>
(function () { document.getElementById("GymName").innerHTML = 'hesham'; }());
</script>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```